# Vuetify 3 beta item-title doesn't accept multiple inputs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

So I have the following:

```js
projects: {id: number, name: string, customer: string} = 
[
    {id:0,name:'foo',customer:'bar'},
    {id:1,name:'foo2',customer:'bar2'}
]
```

I'm trying to build a v-select that uses the customer and name of the project as it's item-title.

By the documentation one would expect to be able to concatenate the attributes or put them in an array. That however isn't the case.
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-title

The following works:

```html
  <v-select
          :items="projects"
          item-title="name"
          return-object
          label="Select project"
     >
<!-- or -->
 <v-select
          :items="projects"
          item-title=""
          return-object
          label="Select project"
     >
```

But trying to pass multiple things into the array or concatenating the string will not work:

```html
 <v-select
          :items="projects"
          item-title="[name,customer]"
          return-object
    >
<!-- or -->
 <v-select
          :items="projects"
          item-title="customer+name"
          return-object
    >
```

Clicking the empty selects works but I want to display `customer + "/" + name` in the title
[Illustration of empty v-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CbNv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to achieve this with default approach but it was not working for me as well. You can achieve this by a workaround for now.

In `onMounted()` lifecycle hook, Manipulate the input array and add a new property in each object which will contain the concatenated value.

```
data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
        { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
        { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
      ],
    }
}

onMounted() {
    this.items = this.items.map(obj => obj.title = obj.state + ' - ' + obj.abbr)
}
```

In HTML Template **:**

```
item-title="title"
```